# Asymptotic of a convolution integral

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, convolution

$f(x) \ge 0$, $g(x) \ge 0$ are defined on $[0,\infty)$ and $f(x) \sim x^{-a}, \  x \to \infty$, where $a>1$. The integrals $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx<\infty$ and $\int_0^\infty g(x) dx<\infty$.

Is it true that  $\int_0^x f(x-u)g(u)du \sim x^{-a}\int_0^\infty g(x) dx, x \to \infty?$

Comment: Well, if $A\sim B$ means $A/B\to1$ then you wouldn't expect to get $x^{-a}$, you'd expect $x^{-a}\int g$.

Comment: Yes. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without extra hypotheses on $g$, or maybe on $f$. The convolution is larger than $$\int_{x-1}^x f(x-t)g(t)\,dt=\int_0^1f(t)g(x-t)\,dt.$$ If, say, $f$ is bounded then that tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, but it can tend to $0$ slower than $x^{-a}$.

Comment: I think it would be enough to assume that $g(x)$  is non increasing, then it must be$ o(x^{-1}), x \to \infty$.

Comment: @kmitov ??? We need $\int_0^1 f(t)g(x-t)\,dt=O(x^{-a})$; that doesn't follow from $g(x)=o(x^{-1})$.

Comment: I hav found the solution.

Comment: @kmitov So tell us...

Comment: I assume that $g(x)=o(x^{-a-1})$. It works.

Comment: If $g(x)$ is also regularly varying with exponent $-b$ with $b>1$ then the convolution is equiwalent to the sum $f(x)+g(x)$.